# Debugging hanging java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec

Tags: java

I'm having an issue pretty much identical to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952597/why-is-java-lang-unixprocess-forkandexecnative-method-hanging) except with a different OS and Java version (his answer seemed to be a Solaris-specific fix, whereas I'm using Linux). Under certain circumstances when I try to run a process from within Java, it completely hangs on `java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec`.

**Circumstances**

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Sep 13 11:24:45 CEST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

(I have not been able to reproduce this with the Sun 1.6.0_27-b07 JDK.)

The subprocess I start is just `ps` with a few arguments. I print out what I run before running it, and when I try the exact same command in the shell after it hangs, `ps` runs just fine.

When it happens, it only happens sometimes (maybe one in 500 runs).

It doesn't hang if I start the subprocess soon after startup. It only happens (and only occasionally) if I start the subprocess after some other things such as string manipulation, opening/communicating/closing a socket with an ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, and reading from a small file.

Because of the infrequency of the hanging, it's hard to narrow it down exactly, but I can definitely reproduce it in about 10 minutes by running the program in a Bash while-true loop until it hangs.

Also I restarted my machine yesterday, so it should be unrelated to the leap-second bug.

**Symptoms**

When it hangs, the stack trace looks like this:

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode):

"process reaper" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f42904dc000 nid=0x14bf waiting on condition [0x00007f427aa2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007c229fbf0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f42900f1000 nid=0x14bc runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f42900ee000 nid=0x14bb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f42900eb000 nid=0x14ba waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f42900e8000 nid=0x14b9 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f429009b800 nid=0x14b8 in Object.wait() [0x00007f427b8f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c00057f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007c00057f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4290099000 nid=0x14b7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f427b9f8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c0005370> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007c0005370> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4290009000 nid=0x14b1 runnable [0x00007f4299077000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:68)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:99)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:147)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:147)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger$$anon$1.buffer(ProcessLogger.scala:64)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:147)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:113)
    at mypackage.Main.main(Main.scala)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4290091800 nid=0x14b6 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4290017000 nid=0x14b2 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4290018800 nid=0x14b3 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f429001a800 nid=0x14b4 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f429001c800 nid=0x14b5 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f42900f5800 nid=0x14bd waiting on condition
```

If I run `jstack -m` or `jstack -F` on the pid after its hung, I get this (same exact output with `-m` and `-F`):

```
$ jstack -m 3199
Attaching to process ID 3199, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Type "nmethodBucket*", referenced in VMStructs::localHotSpotVMStructs in the remote VM, was not present in the remote VMStructs::localHotSpotVMTypes table (should have been caught in the debug build of that VM). Can not continue.
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.lookupOrFail(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:362)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.readVMStructs(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:253)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.<init>(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:87)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupVM(BugSpotAgent.java:568)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:494)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:332)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:163)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
    ... 6 more
```

**Synopsis**

I believe that `java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec` should never hang. If there is a race condition in my own code, it would hang somewhere else; and if the subprocess itself is hung, my Java process would only be hung in `waitFor` but not in `java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec`. It seems like a JVM bug to me, but I'm just not sure how to pinpoint it to a reproducible test case. Any suggestions on what to do next?

**Edit**

When the hang happens, I have two identical java processes show up in top. When I ctrl-c it, the main one exits but the other one remains, and doesn't die until I kill -9. Both processes use 0% CPU.

**Edit**

The child process does nothing when I run `kill -QUIT`.

When I run `pstack` on the child process, I get:

```
#0  0x0000003c2fa0e054 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003c2fa09388 in _L_lock_854 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003c2fa09257 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb79c4c8a30 in __oo_rwlock_unlock_write_slow () from /usr/lib64/libonload.so
#4  0x00007fb79c4990be in citp_netif_child_fork_hook () from /usr/lib64/libonload.so
#5  0x0000003c2f2abb76 in fork () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007fb79b0219f6 in startChild () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
#7  0x00007fb79b0220eb in Java_java_lang_UNIXProcess_forkAndExec () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
#8  0x00007fb791011f90 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007fb700000000 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

When I run `pstack` on the parent process, I get:

```
Thread 17 (Thread 0x7fb79b544700 (LWP 8437)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0e54d in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79c488816 in read () from /usr/lib64/libonload.so
#2  0x00007fb79b022126 in Java_java_lang_UNIXProcess_forkAndExec () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
#3  0x00007fb791011f90 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fb700000000 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Thread 16 (Thread 0x7fb79ab11700 (LWP 8438)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bdfbb2b in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 15 (Thread 0x7fb79aa10700 (LWP 8439)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bdfbb2b in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 14 (Thread 0x7fb79a90f700 (LWP 8440)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bdfbb2b in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 13 (Thread 0x7fb79a80e700 (LWP 8441)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bdfbb2b in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 12 (Thread 0x7fb798100700 (LWP 8442)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b7bb in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc85cd7 in os::PlatformEvent::park(long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4d26e in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79b93b498 in ConcurrentMarkSweepThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 11 (Thread 0x7fb78e2c9700 (LWP 8443)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b7bb in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc85cd7 in os::PlatformEvent::park(long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4d26e in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bded430 in VMThread::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bded970 in VMThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 10 (Thread 0x7fb78e1c8700 (LWP 8444)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc76c5c in ObjectMonitor::wait(long, bool, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79baebc81 in JVM_MonitorWait () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb791011f90 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000007e7802b98 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fb794123000 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fb78e1c7160 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fb78e1c7108 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Thread 9 (Thread 0x7fb78e0c7700 (LWP 8445)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc76c5c in ObjectMonitor::wait(long, bool, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79baebc81 in JVM_MonitorWait () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb791011f90 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fb78e0c6160 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fb7910124ea in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Thread 8 (Thread 0x7fb78dfc6700 (LWP 8446)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d7c6 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79b910cfe in SurrogateLockerThread::loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fb78dec5700 (LWP 8447)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0d720 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc858ca in check_pending_signals(bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc7f9f5 in signal_thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fb78ddc4700 (LWP 8448)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d7c6 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79b903458 in CompileQueue::get() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79b90616a in CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#9  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fb78dcc3700 (LWP 8449)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d7c6 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79b903458 in CompileQueue::get() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79b90616a in CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#9  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fb78dbc2700 (LWP 8450)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b43c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc811b3 in os::PlatformEvent::park() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bc4cfbf in Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc4d74e in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79bd0c9c8 in ServiceThread::service_thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fb78dac1700 (LWP 8451)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0b7bb in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79bc85cd7 in os::PlatformEvent::park(long) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#2  0x00007fb79bda2ae7 in WatcherThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fb78c11f700 (LWP 8501)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa0e84d in accept () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79c489f34 in onload_accept () from /usr/lib64/libonload.so
#2  0x00007fb79b7c5171 in LinuxAttachListener::dequeue() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fb79b7c530b in AttachListener::dequeue() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fb79b7c3d5f in attach_listener_thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fb79bda52e8 in JavaThread::thread_main_inner() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x00007fb79bda5438 in JavaThread::run() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fb79bc870a0 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x0000003c2fa07851 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x0000003c2f2e76dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb79c264da0 (LWP 8413)):
#0  0x0000003c2fa080ad in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb79c2754d5 in ContinueInNewThread0 () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/../jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#2  0x00007fb79c26a4fa in ContinueInNewThread () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/../jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#3  0x00007fb79c26d085 in JLI_Launch () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/../jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#4  0x00000000004006a6 in main ()
```

Comment: The question you have linked to refers to [this bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6671051). The description of the symptoms match. Perhaps they "forgot" to fix Linux also?

Comment: Does the child process respond to `kill -QUIT` or other attempts to get a thread dump? I wonder if that other process can give you any information about what it is (or isn't) doing.

Comment: A.H. good point, although the one thing that makes me think this is separate is the fact that in my case it never crashes in java 6, but occasionally crashes in java 7, so it seems like it's a regression in java 7 (unless the bug was always there and java 7 just coincidentally has different latencies somewhere that make it much more likely to show up).

Comment: Also, can you run `pstack` against the child (or parent) process?

Comment: wondering if you have tried using Thread Dump Analyzer from IBM. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c

Comment: Christopher: I'm editing the question to show `kill -QUIT` and `pstack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Christopher Schultz for suggesting running `pstack` on the child process.

It appears that libonload was causing the problem. It was not reproducible when running without onload, and also not reproducible when upgrading onload to the latest version (although nothing like this was in the changelog).

Comment: Can you provide more details on this. I am having the same problem :(

Comment: @Geek what version of onload are you using? Have you tried EF_VFORK_MODE=2?

Answer (score 1):

I found few bugs in oracle site on forkandexec in Linux & SunOS
But these bugs are already fixed in your java 1.7

Seeing the stack trace, i feel the thread is waiting on some condition.
Can you please check if your code use any of these methods like

```
get()
```

or

```
poll()
```

As these method will land the thread in TIMED_WAITING state.

i suggest to monitor more in detail using Jvisualvm tool avail in jdk/bin
Am sure u will be able to find the root cause.

You can monitor both the child & parent thread using the same.
Let me know if have any issue launch & analyzing your program.

Comment: I'm not sure how any of my code could effect the stuck thread, since it's in a native method in RUNNABLE instead of TIMED_WAITING. My code is also single threaded at this point in the execution, so there is no child or parent thread, just the main thread that ultimately ends up in forkAndExec.