# Linux - Why is UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) hanging

Tags: java, process

I have Java unit tests running on Linux on HotSpot 8u162.  One test case executes `bash -c echo Hello` via [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  Most of the time this test case works fine and performs quickly.  Rarely this test case will take a very long time to execute (e.g. 31 minutes).  The thread is stuck in this call stack for the entire time.

```
"MyTestCase" Id=652 RUNNABLE
   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
   ...
```

I am not getting any exceptions.  `ProcessBuilder.start()` eventually returns normally.  The test case passes.  Even if the child process was hung, `ProcessBuilder.start()` should return and then I can read from `Process.getInputStream()`.

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this issue?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952597/solaris-why-is-java-lang-unixprocess-forkandexecnative-method-hanging) is similar but for Solaris.  There is an [old JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4373248) for 1.3.0 but it was fixed in 1.4.0.

Here is my Java version.

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Here is my distilled code.  The unit test is actually testing a wrapper class that basically executes this code.

```
new ProcessBuilder().
   command("bash", "-c", "echo Hello").
   redirectInput(new File("/dev/null")).
   redirectErrorStream(true).
   redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE).
   start();
```

Comment: Why are you executing a bash process to print Hello to a PIPE? Read [this](https://superuser.com/q/559709/272880).

Comment: Because this is a very simple process that should never fail

Comment: `ulimit -a` shows `max user processes 32768`.  I highly doubt I am getting anywhere near this limit.  Besides, wouldn't `ProcessBuilder.start()` throw an exception if this limit were reached instead of hanging?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.  You are clearly doing more than your "distilled" code fragment.  Turn your unit test into a stand-alone Java application that we can run to reproduce what you are seeing.  (Note: often people find that when they try to create the MCVE they find the cause of the original problem ... themselves.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `UNIXProcess.forkAndExec()` stalled for so long is because the program was sending a lot of writes to the disk.  The disk was maxed out with a long backlog of writes.  The OS could not start the process quickly because the OS needed to access the disk.